# how to refresh cache data in iis?

Tags: asp.net, iis, caching, browser

I have a website that is in development phase. I deploy it every week on server. However cache data is a big problem for me. For example, after deployment, Default.aspx page still remains same. So css,js or other files.. 
How can I achieve this problem ? I have checked for iis configurations and there is no any record or checked options, under HTTP response headers or cache menu.

edit: in web.config file:

```
<staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
</staticContent>
<caching enabled="true" enableKernelCache="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you need to recycle your application pools to ensure nothing is retained loaded in memory.

Comment: Try putting a new file in place (such as test.txt, with just "hello world") and see if you can navigate to it.  This will help prove you're ending up on the site you think you are.